# select two most recent entries for each part

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Access 2013. Table1 has PK quote_id and is a list of quotes for different parts sourced from different vendors. How do I pull the top 2 most recent quotes for every part,vendor combination?

This is what I am currently using, but in terms of performance it is very inefficient. Is there a better query to achieve this? Thanks

```
SELECT a.part_id, a.vendor_id, a.quote_date
FROM Table1 AS a
WHERE a.quote_date > DATEADD("yyyy", -3, DATE()) AND 
a.quote_date IN 
 (SELECT TOP 2 quote_date 
 FROM Table1 
 WHERE quote_date > DATEADD("yyyy", -3, DATE()) AND 
 part_id=a.part_id AND vendor_id=a.vendor_id 
 ORDER BY quote_date DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work but no way to test it from here -

Select part_id, vendor_id, quote_date
From (SELECT a.part_id, a.vendor_id, a.quote_date,
Row_Number() Over (Partition By a.part_id, a.vendor_id Order By a.quote_date desc) as quote_Date_Seq
FROM Table1 AS a
WHERE a.quote_date > DATEADD("yyyy", -3, DATE()) b
Where b.quote_Date_Seq <= 2

Comment: i dont think access supports row num or partition by :(